# What is the correct way to ask about something that happened some time ago?

Tags: meaning, tenses, present-perfect, present-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

When I took one test I had to choose between four options:

a) **Did you hear that he has been assigned to a new project last week?**

b) **Have you heard that he has been assigned to a new project last week?**

c) **Have you heard that he was assigned to a new project last week?**

d) **Did you hear that he is assigned to a new project last week?**

And I'm confused, because different translators translate as "**Did you hear he was assigned** to a new project last week?"

As I know "was" is used then there is a time marker. So it is.
However there are no such option.

And I'm confused about using "Did you hear" and "Have you heard?"
When you search "Did you hear" - google returns 93.3 million results
"Have you heard" - only 56.5 million.

Comment: The examiners doubtless want (c). I wonder how many of them realise that (a) is also grammatical. And arguably (d).

Comment: thank you for your opinion. I just hesitated between a and c.

Comment: (a) has the '[As we know,] he has been assigned to a new project. Did you hear about this last week?' meaning. And (d) is similarly available.